# How to calculate probability of picking the same items without knowing number of items or which ones?

Tags: probability

Let’s say you have n items. A random number of these items are being selected from each other with no replacement. How would you calculate the odds of two people randomly drawing the same items independently without having a defined number of items?

For instance, let’s say you had three items: 1,2,3. The odds of calculating are as follows:
With 1 item, there are possible choices 1, 2, 3 which means there are 3 choices. With 2 items, there are possible choices 1-2, 1-3, 2-3, which means number of choices also equals 3. With 3 items, the possible choice is 1-2-3, which means only one choice. The probability of getting the same result is 1/7.
How would you calculate this on a larger scale, such as 20?

Comment: The correct solution? What does that mean?

Comment: I edited my post again to make it more clear by adding an example. Hopefully it makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

One possible interpretation of this rather vague question is to think that two people have independently and uniformly chosen one of the $2^n$ subsets of an $n$ element set.

The probability that they choose the same set is $1/2^n$. When $n=20$ that's about $1$ in a million.